# Creating thumbnails from an image in Java

Tags: java

Is there an Api for creating a thumbnail from a JPEG?

Answer (score 3):

Just draw the image at a smaller scale.

There is a good article on the topic: [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are deffinetly tools.

I myself created a Utility class with image operations.

Basically you can use

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, newWidth, newHeight, filter);
```

Using the classes [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) and [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)
Also note that BitmapFactory has a nested class; [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html)
You can create a more powerful thumbnail-er aswell.

The above method doesnt really care about proper aspects ratio's as far as I know.

Edit##Completely didn't notice this post is a few years old -_-

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems to do so with BufferedImage, this solution was best I've found:

```
    BufferedImage original; // comes from elsewhere
    BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, original.getType());
    Graphics2D g = resized.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.drawImage(original, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, 0, 0, originalWidth, originalHeight, null);
    g.dispose();
```